Flutter Launcher Icons Not Updating Properly on Android
I'm experiencing an issue with the flutter_launcher_icons package in my Flutter project. While the default Flutter icon seems to be overridden, a black icon appears instead of my custom launcher icon. I've followed the steps from this flutter_launcher_icons package is not changing the launcher icons in android after upgrading to the latest flutter version  guidance post, but I’m still facing problems.
name: quotncode
description: "A new Flutter project."
publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ^3.5.3

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.8
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.4.1
  webview_flutter: ^4.9.0
  webview_flutter_wkwebview: ^3.15.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.14.1
  webview_flutter_android: ^3.16.7

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^4.0.0

flutter_launcher_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  remove_alpha_ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"  # Updated path to my actual icon
  adaptive_icon_background: "#ffffff"
  adaptive_icon_foreground: "assets/icon/icon.png"

flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#ffffff"
  image: assets/icon/icon.png

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

Path to my icon image:
D:\flutter\flutter-webview\quotncode\quotncode\assets\icon\icon.png
Steps I've Taken:
Verified that the image exists at the specified path and is a valid image format (PNG).
Ensured the correct configuration in pubspec.yaml.
Ran the command: flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main.
Cleaned the project using flutter clean.
Rebuilt the project.
Observations:
The default Flutter launcher icon is being overridden.
However, a black icon appears instead of my custom launcher icon.
Additional Information:
I'm using Flutter version Flutter 3.24.3.
I've tested the app on both an Android emulator and a physical device.
What could be causing this issue? Any suggestions on how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated!
here is overriden some blackcolor icon image screenshot
enter image description here

Black icon as in where? In notification?

https://i.sstatic.net/U9AWHmED.jpg
check this image

Were you able to find a solution? I'm facing the same issue

The last thing I did before it stopped working was upgrade to Ladybug.  I'm adding that comment in case it helps.  I made changes to AGP in order to get the app to build at all.  Then noticed the black image - just as Pugazhendhi attached.

I had the same issue. I believe there is a bug in flutter_launcher_icons.
It worked for me after deleting the launcher_icon.xml file in android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-anydpi-v26, which was generated by dart run flutter_launcher_icons.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Thank you it worked after downgrading to "^0.13.1"

i have follow delete the folder anydpi-v26 and i have downgrading to ^0.13.1 but the icon is still dark, it's nor working for me

This worked to me, there is a related issue on GitHub
https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_launcher_icons/issues/579

Downgrade plugin version to 0.13.1 and try again.
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1

Problem should be solved, if not checkout this answer and then try again.

use icons_launcher instade
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  icons_launcher: ^3.0.0

icons_launcher:
  image_path: "assets/icon.png"
  platforms:
    android:
      enable: true
    ios:
      enable: true

see:
https://pub.dev/packages/icons_launcher
